# Error: Not Found at app.use.res.render.message in nodejs / expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I have setup new express (nodejs) project and while I tried to run url it shows me an error of 404 not found error. Yet I have not modified any single line of code and directory structure. I have used express-generator command to create express project's structure.

Can anyone provide me suggestions for following issues?
 - Why default code does not run?
 - How should I setup my project directory to prevent write this long url.
 - How could I integrate my chat application with yii1 project.

Following are my code details.

URL : http://localhost:3000/wchat/wnode/users

Directory structure : 
wchat/wnode/users
wchat : php project
wnode : node directory to implements instant notification and chat 
users : module

Code files :
app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {

   message: err.message,
   error: {}
  });
});
module.exports = app;
```

index.js

```
   var express = require('express');
   var router = express.Router();

   /* GET home page. */
   router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
   });

   module.exports = router;
```

users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Error :

```
Not Found
404
Error: Not Found
    at app.use.res.render.message (/var/www/html/wchat/wnode/app.js:30:13)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/wchat/wnode/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/var/www/html/wchat/wnode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /var/www/html/wchat/wnode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/var/www/html/wchat/wnode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/var/www/html/wchat/wnode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at /var/www/html/wchat/wnode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:15
    at next (/var/www/html/wchat/wnode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:256:14)
    at Function.handle (/var/www/html/wchat/wnode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
    at router (/var/www/html/wchat/wnode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
```

Comment: Its `res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });` not `es.render('index', { title: 'Express' });` in index.js. I did not see how you are trying to handle the url `wchat/wnode/users` in routes. Update your question with route handler `users.js`

Comment: Thank you swaraj,
due to copy paste it may remove.

Comment: Where is `routes/users` ?

Comment: I have updated users.js.
Even without users for default route index is not working and showing me same error : http://localhost:3000/wchat/wnode/

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your routes,

```
app.use('/', routes); -> handlers GET on localhost:3000
app.use('/users', users); -> handles GET on localhost:3000/users
```

So there is nothing to handle `localhost:3000/wchat/wnode/users`. Hence the 404.

If you want to handle something like `localhost:3000/wchat/wnode/users`,
you need to have a route like

```
router.verb('/wchat/wnode/users', function (req, res, next) {
  // handle whatever you want.
});
```

Looking at your code and what url you are trying to GET, i would really suggest to familiarize yourself with how express handles routing. More info [here](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router)

Comment: Thank but rather use /wchat/wnode/users can I use /user to run route .. Is there any way to define shorten url in case if we have 2-3 level of directory structure.

Comment: You can do what you want on `/users` instead of making a long url like `/wchat/wnode/users`